# Let $\Lambda_A$ be a lattice with a basis $A= (a_1,a_2,a_3)...$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\Lambda_A$ be a lattice with a basis $A= (a_1,a_2,a_3),$ where $a_1=(1,1,1)^T,a_2=(1,0,2)^T$, and $a_3=(0,1,1)^T$. Let $\Lambda_B$ be a lattice with a basis $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, where $b_1=(1,2,6)^T,b_2=(3,1,3)^T,$ and $b_3=(3,3,7)^T$ Show that $\Lambda_B$ is a sublattice of $\Lambda_A$. Find the index of $\Lambda_B$ in$\Lambda_A.$

This is the way I approached this:

Let $\Lambda_o$ be a sublattice of a lattice $\Lambda$, then$[\Lambda:\Lambda_o]=|det\Lambda_o|/|det\Lambda|$.

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 &1  \\
1 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
= \;
1\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
 \;
-1\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
+ \;
0\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$  = det $A=-2$.

$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 3\\ 
2 & 1 &3  \\
6 & 3 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
= \;
1\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3\\ 
3 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
 \;
-3\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\ 
6 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
+ \;
3\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\ 
2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$  = det $B=10$.

This would be a sublattice since the determinants are divisible. Did I take the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You have observed that $\det \Lambda_A$ divides $\det \Lambda_B$. Thus, if $\Lambda_A$ is a sublattice of $\Lambda_B$, then the index is $$[\Lambda_B : \Lambda_A] = |\det \Lambda_B| / |\det \Lambda_A| =5.$$
However, divisibility doesn't imply that $\Lambda_A \subset \Lambda_B$, i.e. you need to show that any $b_1,b_2,b_3$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ with integral coefficients.

For example, the lattice $\Lambda$ spanned by $(1,1/2)$ and $(0,1)$ has determinant $1$. However, $\Lambda \not\subset \mathbb{Z}^2$, although it divides $\det \mathbb{Z}^2 =1$.

**Edit:** Let us show that the index is, in fact, the quotient of the determinants. (This argument can be also found in the below mentioned book of Cassels.)

Given a lattice $\Lambda_0$ and a sublattice $\Lambda_1 \subset \Lambda_0$, we can view both as groups. So $[\Lambda_1 : \Lambda_0]$ is the number of cosets. One standard fact is that there exists a basis $b_1, \ldots b_n$ of $\Lambda_1$ such that $a_i = \sum_{j=1}^i u_{i,j} b_j$ with some $u_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a basis. (See e.g. in the book 'Introduction to Geometry of Numbers' of Cassels.) Thus
$$\det \Lambda_1 = \prod_{i=1}^n u_{i,i} \det \Lambda_0.$$
On the other hand any
$$c= \sum_{i=1}^n n_i b_i$$
with $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n_i < |u_{i,i}|$ gives some different point in $\Lambda_0 \backslash \Lambda_1$ and this are all points, as can be checked. Thus, we find that
$$[\Lambda_0 : \lambda_1| = \prod_{i=1}^n |u_{i,i}| = |\det \Lambda_0| / |\det{\Lambda_1}|.$$

Comment: So i have to find coefficients for $b_1,b_2,b_3$? Now the second part is to find the index, and my definition states Index is the number of cosets of $\Lambda_o$. Do you have any links or examples that I can work with?

Comment: Added one comment in my answer: I show that the index is, in fact, the quotient of both determinants. You have only to find the linear combinations. (This can be done by solving system of linear equations.) For example $b_1 = u a_1 + v a_2 + w a_3$ implies that $1=u+v$, $2=u+w$ and $6=2v+w$. This has the solution $u=-2/3$, $v=5/3$ and $w=8/3$. Thus, it isn't a sublattice.